# Brief explanation on tensorflow object detection working mechanism

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets

I've searched for working mechanism of tensorflow object detection in google. I've searched how tensorflow train models with dataset. It give me suggestion about how to implement rather than how it works.
Can anyone explain how dataset are trained in fit into models?

Answer (score 0):

You can't "simply" understand how Tensorflow works without a good background on Artificial Intelligence and Machine Learning.

I suggest you start working on those topics. Tensorflow will get much easier to understand and to handle after that.